# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'max'

Tags: python, function

This is the continuation of my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414913/normalize-columns-of-pandas-data-frame/48651066) on normalizing columns of a Pandas DataFrame with a specific condition for negative value.

The DataFrame I'm using is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'key' : [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999],
                   'score1' : [-1, 0, 2, -1, 7, 0, 15, 0, 1], 
                   'score2' : [2, 2, -1, 10, 0, 5, -1, 1, 0]})

print(df)

   key  score1  score2
0  111      -1       2
1  222       0       2
2  333       2      -1
3  444      -1      10
4  555       7       0
5  666       0       5
6  777      15      -1
7  888       0       1
8  999       1       0
```

The possible values for the `score1` and `score2` Series are `-1` and all positive integers (including `0`). My goal was to normalize both columns the following way:

- If the value is equal to `-1`, then return a missing `NaN` value
- Else, normalize the remaining positive integers on a range between `0` and `1`.

I'm extremely happy with the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57851077/normalizing-pandas-series-with-condition) from **ezrael**.  That being said, I continued working on my problem to see if I could come up with an alternate solution. Here's my try:

1. I'm defining the following function:

```
def normalize(x):
    if x == -1:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x/x.max()
```

2. I'm creating the new `norm1` Series by applying the above function to the `score1` Series:

```
df['norm1'] = df['score1'].apply(normalize)
```

Unfortunately, this raises the following `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'max'`.

I converted the `score1` Series to `float64` but it does not fix the problem: `'float' object has no attribute 'max'`.

I also did a quick test by replacing the second ´return´ statement with `return x/15` (`15` being the maximum value of the `score1` Series) and it worked:

```
   key  score1  score2     norm1
0  111    -1.0       2       NaN
1  222     0.0       2  0.000000
2  333     2.0      -1  0.133333
3  444    -1.0      10       NaN
4  555     7.0       0  0.466667
5  666     0.0       5  0.000000
6  777    15.0      -1  1.000000
7  888     0.0       1  0.000000
8  999     1.0       0  0.066667
```

But this is not a viable solution. I want to be able to divide by the maximum value of the Series instead of hard-coding it. **WHY** is my solution not working and **HOW** do I fix my code?

Comment: You function is being called one time for each element of the Series.  It has no (direct) access to the entire Series, which would be required to call `.max()` on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason of `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'max'` error is that with your code you are calling the max() function on every (float) items of your column, you can pass the max value of your column to the `normalize` function:

```
def normalize(x, col_max):
    if x == -1:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x/col_max
```

And edit the norm1 column creation code as follow:

```
df['norm1'] = df['score1'].apply(lambda x: normalize(x, df['score1'].max()))
```

Comment: @FavbioL thank you! should compute the max just once (df['score1'].max()) instead of per row, otherwise, there is a large performance penalty for large dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using a function that takes a series as the input rather than a scalar:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'key' : [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999],
                   'score1' : [-1, 0, 2, -1, 7, 0, 15, 0, 1],
                   'score2' : [2, 2, -1, 10, 0, 5, -1, 1, 0]})

df['norm1'] = df['score1'].replace(-1, np.nan)


def normalize_series(s):
    return (s - s.min()) / (s.max() - s.min())


df['norm1'] = normalize_series(df['norm1'])
```

As already mentioned, your version isn't working because you are trying to find the max of a single number, not a series.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand what the "apply" function does : the 'x' argument of 'apply' is in fact a row (if you apply f on a pd.Dataframe object) or directly the only value of the row (if you are manipulating a pd.Series object).

You are in the second case. Imagine, instead of a pd.Series, that you have got a list.

```py
L = [1,2,3,4,5]

def normalize(x):
    return(x/max(x))

normalize(L)
```

It is here clear that max(x) does not make any sense. What you are looking for is `max(L)`.

So this would be technically okay :

```py
L = [1,2,3,4,5]

def normalize(x):
    return(x/max(L))

normalize(L)
```

But not very efficient, since you are recomputing max(L) at every iteration. So

```py
L = [1,2,3,4,5]
max_L = max(L)
def normalize(x,max_L):
    return(x/max_L)

normalize(L)
```

would be the answer you are looking for. With pd.Series, it gives

```
def normalize(x, col_max):
    if x == -1:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x/col_max

df['norm1'] = df['score1'].apply(lambda x: normalize(x, df['score1'].max()))
```

Note that it is not necessary to replace NaNs by -1 to compute min() and max(), you just have to use nanmin() and nanmax(). You can separate the operations like this :

```
def create_nans(x):
    if x == -1:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x

def normalize(x, col_max):
    return(x/col_max) # make sure col_max != 0 or NaN

df['score1'] = df['score1'].apply(create_nans)
df['norm1'].apply(lambda x: normalize(x, df['score1'].nanmax()))
```